# deleting all files from a folder on Linux server using PHP

Tags: php, linux

My question is almost the same as this one [Deleting all files from a folder using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594180/deleting-all-files-from-a-folder-using-php)

And I tried to use the answer provided by @Floern https://stackoverflow.com/a/4594262/2167772

But it didn't work for me. I tried to get filenames from a folder on the Linux server. And I have changed the folder and file permission to rwxrwxrwx. And I got the "Unable to get the filename" message all the time. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

```
     $files=glob('/data/in/*') or die ("Unable to get the filename");
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    if(is_file($file)){
                        echo $file;
                        unlink($file) or die ("Uable to delete file!");
                    }       
                }
```

------Update----

I just figured it out. It is the problem with the server. I cannot write anything to the data folder even I assign the write permission. I will move my in folder to another folder.

Thank you so much for everyone's comments!

Comment: So the question really is "why does `glob` fail"? How would we know?

Comment: use scandir() end exclude files that are directories with testing `is_dir($item)`

Comment: do you actually have `/data` directory in the root of your file system? I doubt it... you probably have `/data` in your site's document root, but that's going to be `/some/other/path/site/docroot/data`, not just `/data`

Comment: @Jon I don't think you understand my question. glob works for other people. So the question is not "why does glob fail". If I know what the question is, I will not post a question here.

Comment: @user2167772: If you get "unable to get the filename" then that means `glob` fails. Which means that you want to find out why `glob` fails. There is only a single argument to `glob`. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its answered [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24810837/3799829) check answers cmon ..

Answer (score 0):

As said @Marc B, you just have to write this :

```
 $files=glob('data/in/*') or die ("Unable to get the filenames!");
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if(is_file($file)){
                    echo $file;
                    unlink($file) or die ("Unable to delete file!");
                }       
            }
```

You write : `glob('/data/in/*')`, I write `glob('data/in/*')`

You use absolute path, i use relative path.

Comment: Hi Bob0t and @Marc B. Thank you for your comments. I tried the relative path. It doesn't work. I do have a /data directory in the root of my file system

Comment: ah then its  not this solution :v

Comment: It is the problem with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial:
http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.rmdir.php#107233

And check is your folder permission is enable to write.

Have you trying like this:

```
$dir = 'your/directory/';
foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v){
    unlink($v);
}
```

Comment: Quote `And I have changed the folder and file permission to rwxrwxrwx` he allready checked permissiosn, he just failed glob() func cuz he used absolute path :)

Comment: did you put 777 permission?

Comment: he put `rwxrwxrwx` wich is same

Answer (score 0):

if file is not at public directory...

change mode of file to 777

```
  $files=glob('data/in/*') or die ("Unable to get the filename");
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if(is_file($file)){
                    echo $file;
                       chmod($file,777);
                    unlink($file) or die ("Uable to delete file!");
                }       
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

solution with php. don't like the `glob` function. you can use the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

```
    $filePath = '/someDir';
    $directoryIterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(realpath($filePath));
    foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator) as $object ) {
        if(!$object->isDir())
        {
            unlink($object->getPath());
        }
    }
```