# deleting all files from a folder, excluding some files from being deleted

Tags: php, delete-file

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594180/deleting-all-files-from-a-folder-using-php) thread (first post) I have successfully accomplished the task of deleting all files from a folder using php.

This is the code I use:

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

I would like to exclude some files from being deleted. What code adjustment should I apply?

Comment: Do you have list of files what you wouldn't delete?

Comment: Which files do you want to exclude? Of specific type? size? What's the logic that you want to apply?

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/*'); // get all file names
$exceptions = ["awesomefile_a", "awesomefile_b"];
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file) && !in_array(end(explode("/", $file)), $exceptions))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```