# Removing directory and its contents in php

Tags: php

I am trying to remove folders and its files and sub folders using php.

This is how I tried it.

```
$dir     = "../../images/$category_id/$delId"; 
$it      = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()){
        rmdir($file->getRealPath());
    } else {
        unlink($file->getRealPath());
    }
}
rmdir($dir);
```

This is working on php 5.5+, but is doesn't work in php 5.2.17.

Can anybody tell me how I get it to work on 5.2 also. 
Thank you.

Comment: is there any error of 5.2! what exactly is the response you get?

Comment: @SaurabhSinha, yes there is an error `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Undefined class constant 'SKIP_DOTS' in <b>/home2/public_html/admin
/includes/process_edit.php</b> on line <b>124</b><br />`

Comment: Here you can definitely find several ways to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594180/deleting-all-files-from-a-folder-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
function rrmdir($dir) { 
  foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
    if(is_dir($file)) rrmdir($file); else unlink($file); 
  } rmdir($dir); 
}
```

You can also simply do it by below statement:-

```
system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));
```

Hope it will help you :)