# PHP empty directory without recursive function

Tags: php, directory

Can anyone suggest the best way to empty a folder using PHP. I do not want to use the recursive approach. Is there any alternative and what is that function/approach?

Thanks

Comment: Best way I would suggest.Just delete the folder and create new one with same name .

Comment: @BikashP - Alright, so you suggest using the rmdir function

Comment: `rmdir` won't work if directory is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a combination of `array_map`, `unlink` and [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) like  this :

```
array_map('unlink', glob("/path/to/folder/*"));
```

Credits to [Stichoza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468943/4864023)

Comment: No i haven't. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. wouldn't rmdir() to remove the directory and creating it again be faster?

Comment: `rmdir` is not working if there are files inside the directory you are trying to remove..

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
array_map('unlink', glob("path/test/*"));
```